# Напечатать брошюрой любой документ Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, печать

Для экономии листов бумаги хочу печатать договора в режиме брошюра, т.е. 2 страницы на альбомном листе. Но так как страниц всего 4, то правильно будет печатать одну строну (внешние страницы) - 4 и 1, а вторую сторону 2 и 3. Соответственно сложив их пополам я получу идеальную брошюру и сэкономлю 3 листа бумаги.
А если документ имеет 100 листов, то надо:

1. Печать внутренних страниц: 2,3, 6,7, 10,11 и т.д. до 98,99.
2. Печать внешних страниц: 4,1, 8,5, 12,9 и т.д. до 100,97.

Это все можно делать и вручную, но для оператора ПК (бабуля пенсионного возраста) это почти высшая математика.
Я не знаком с макросами и VBA, но точно знаю, что такое возможно реализовать. Может кто-то уже имеет реализацию такой возможности, надстройку для Word. Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: Печать в pdf, а оттуда брошюру.

Comment: А вы вручную можете это осуществить? Дело в том, что то, что вы хотите осуществить, называется "спуск полос". Это сделать в Word - можно (http://www.idlazur.ru/art57.php). Соответственно можно и в VBA

Comment: надо что бы нажать кнопку и оно само распределило что и как и выпустило на печать. Без дополнительных действий. С таким успехом могу прямо в Word выбрать 2 странице на листе и Ctrl+C "4,1, 8,5, 12,9 и т.д. до 100,97" и Ctrl+V, перевернуть листы в принтере и Ctrl+C "4,1, 8,5, 12,9 и т.д. до 100,97" + Ctrl+V в номера страниц.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра дополнительно, принтер должен поддерживать двухстороннюю печать.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра. Т.е. смысл какой. Если вы сможете это сделать вручную (даже без всяких копи-паст). То вы сможете записать свои действия в макрос Word. Сотвественно там увидите код. Дальше - дело техники. Ну, и немного справки по VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое Sublihim за комментарии. Теперь даю ответ на свой вопрос, если кто еще ищет ответ.

Самое главное. Проследите, чтобы количество страниц в документе было чётным. По необходимости вставте пустую страницу. Необходимо установить простую утилиту FinePrint. Она ставит виртуальный драйвер принтера и печать в макросе будет производится на этот драйвер. Это все нужно для предварительного просмотра того, что сделает макрос. Возможно необходимо будет немного изменить верстку документа для нормального вида. Нужно все лишь закрыть окно FinePrint, изменить документ и опять запустить макрос. Еще FinePrint имеет возможность двухсторонней печати и "умным" мастером настройки. Вот собственно сам код макроса:

```
Sub Спуск_полос_двухсторонняя_печать()
    '
    ' Спуск_полос_двухсторонняя_печать Макрос
    '
    'задаю номер первой страницы
    nPageStart = 1

    'количество листов в документе
    nPageFinish = ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)

    For nCounter = nPageStart To nPageFinish / 2
        sPageMin = Trim(Str(nCounter))
        sPageMax = Trim(Str(nPageFinish - nCounter + 1))

        'если внешние страницы
        If nCounter Mod 2 > 0 Then
            sPagesPrint = sPageMax + "," + sPageMin
        Else
        'если внутренние страницы
            sPagesPrint = sPageMin + "," + sPageMax
        End If

        'постройка строки номеров страниц для печати
        If nCounter = 1 Then
            sListOfPages = sListOfPages + sPagesPrint
       Else
            sListOfPages = sListOfPages + "," + sPagesPrint
       End If
    Next

    'параметры страницы, что бы все влезло
    'мой совет. Сначала попробуйте без параметров страницы.
    'Если не понравится, вот готовый код, только меняйте значения
    With Selection.PageSetup
        .LineNumbering.Active = False
        .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
        .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.2)
        .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.2)
        .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.2)
        .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.2)
        .Gutter = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1)
        .FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1)
        .PageWidth = CentimetersToPoints(21)
        .PageHeight = CentimetersToPoints(29.7)
        .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
        .OtherPagesTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
        .SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
        .SuppressEndnotes = False
        .MirrorMargins = True
        .TwoPagesOnOne = False
        .BookFoldPrinting = False
        .BookFoldRevPrinting = False
        .BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
        .GutterPos = wdGutterPosLeft
    End With

    'настройки печати
    ActivePrinter = "FinePrint"
    Application.PrintOut , Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Item:= _
    wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:=sListOfPages _
    , PageType:=wdPrintAllPages, _
    Collate:=True, PrintToFile:=False, PrintZoomColumn:=2, _
    PrintZoomRow:=1, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
End Sub
```